# How to pass entire jqGrid to Java Controller

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid

From what I managed to achieve was to get all the ID using Jquery below :

```
var ids = jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<c:url value="/xxx/xxxx"/>',
        data: { myArray : ids},
        success: function(response){



        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);

        }
    });
```

How to get the entire jqGrid table data and pass to server side ?

Java

```
public @ResponseBody LocForm saveAccountConfirmation(@RequestParam(value="myArray[]") List<String> myArray ,  ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
```

Comment: Probably you can simplify the problem by posting comma separated list of ids. You need just use `ids.join()` in JavaScript code and parse the string using `.split(",")` on the server side. to get array of ids back.

Answer (score 0):

To get the entire data of the grid you can use **getRowData** method without parameter. More on the methods you can find on [Guriddo jqGrid documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/) (see methods)

Comment: What object do i need to set on Java to get the whole jqgrid table ?

Comment: It is out of jqGrid scope, but you can stringify the array of jqGrid data (JSON.stringify)  send it to the server as string and at server side you can parse it to what you want (it is a json string)